# Linkedin API get company's follower list

Tags: php, linkedin-api

So I need to get my company's followers details.

I tried this :

```
public function getCompanyFollowers($company_id=""){
    if(!$company_id)return false;
    $params['url'] = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/".$company_id.":(num-followers)";
    $params['method']='get';
    $params['args']['format']='json';
    $result =  $this->makeRequest($params);
    return json_decode($result,true);
}
```

but that only returns the count of followers.

On the Linkedin Company page if you click on that number of followers link we can see a list of detailed followers. 
How can I get that list of detailed followers with Linkedin API ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this question myself today.

At the time of writing this response, accessing a detailed list of followers for a LinkedIn company page is not an option in the company API endpoint.

For a full list of supported company API fields such as `num-followers` used in your example, see [this page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/company-profile).

It's possible to list companies that the current logged-in user follows via the people endpoint:

`http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/following/companies`

It's not possible to list people that follow a company via the people or companies endpoints.

Answer (score -3):

https://github.com/criexe/api/wiki/Social-Networks-Page-Stats-API

GET `https://api.criexe.com/social/pageStats?linkedin=1035`

Result (JSON)

```
{
   "linkedin":{
      "company":"1035",
      "followers":4342231
   },
   "total":4342231
}
```

Comment: Very nice ... but why do I get the impression that they are just scraped results from those platforms ? 
What I search is an API that returns full data of the company account followers, not only the total number.

Comment: This website seems now to be down.